# Are there any cases to use pyyaml FullLoader or BaseLoader instead of SafeLoader?

Tags: python, pyyaml

I'm aware that for the Python pyyaml package, using `yaml.safe_load(path)` or `yaml.load(path, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)` is much safer than using the old `Loader` class, which has now been renamed to `UnsafeLoader`. However I've come across some instances of `BaseLoader` and `FullLoader` on a codebase I'm working on, and am debating whether to change it.

[These docs mention](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/wiki/PyYAML-yaml.load(input)-Deprecation) that there are security issues with `FullLoader` as of pyyaml 5.3.1. The latest version is pyyaml 6.0, so I'm not sure whether these issues have been fixed yet.

And I haven't heard of any reason why not to use the `BaseLoader` class, except that it only constructs basic python objects such as strings or lists. Maybe this makes it harder to deserialise data, but also quicker? Is it equally safe as `SafeLoader` though?

The questions then are:

1. Is there any valid use case for preferring `BaseLoader` or `FullLoader` over `SafeLoader`? Or conversely, are there any disadvantages to using `SafeLoader` over `BaseLoader`/`FullLoader`?
2. Is `BaseLoader` equally "safe" as `SafeLoader`?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR

1. Yes, the choice of the loader depends on your data and whether the data source is trusted.
2. Yes, it is.

After digging in the source code, I've figured some things out:
All loaders inherit from many other classes, most of which are the same for any loader. The difference is in constructors and resolvers. `BaseLoader` uses `BaseResolver` and other loaders use `Resolver`. Every loader uses its own constructor (`BaseConstructor`, `SafeConstructor`, `FullConstructor`).

Here we have an interesting thing: `FullConstructor` extends `SafeConstructor` and `SafeConstructor` extends `BaseConstructor`. Which means that `BaseLoader` is as safe (or even safer!) as `SafeLoader`. However, `BaseLoader` doesn't parse any scalars (integers, booleans etc.) and leaves them as strings, which may be not so acceptable in some cases. Sometimes it's very useful though, that's actually what [I needed](https://github.com/Krutyi-4el/python-i18n/issues/4).

`FullLoader` may be necessary when you're parsing yaml that `SafeLoader` can't handle. For example, referring to Python variables:

```
>>> someval = "123"                                     
>>> yaml.load("!!python/name:__main__.someval", Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
'123'
>>> yaml.load("!!python/name:__main__.someval", Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
(long traceback here)
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/name:__main__.someval'
  in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 1:
    !!python/name:__main__.someval
    ^
```